# How to add an Appendix to a two-columns article which should be in a one-column format?

Tags: two-column, article, appendix

I would like to add an Appendix to a two-column article at the end, but the Appendix should be in a one-column format on a new page with alphabet page numbering. This is my document class:

```
% Thesis report
%  
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,%
  nofootinbib,aps,superscriptaddress,%
  eqsecnum,prd,notitlepage,showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % generate random text, remove later...

% page number add middle bottom
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Add my name add top left corner
\lhead{author} % controls the left corner of the header
\rhead{ University }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% To get keywords in abstract
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index terms---}} #1}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{author  }
\affiliation{University}
\date{date}

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}
% Add keywords to abstract
\keywords{one, two, three}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Data}
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Results}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Conclusion\_and\_Discussion}
\begin{acknowledgments}
We thank\dots
\end{acknowledgments}
%\begin{thebibliography}{9}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliography{myrefs}
%\end{thebibliography}

\section{Appendix} % Appendix needs to be on a new full page (not two column but one column) with alphabetic page numbers.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Putting `\onecolumn` before your appendices might help.

Comment: @PeterWilson From what I can tell, revtex4-2 does not define that command. Do you have to use revtex4-2? That makes this *much* more difficult.

Comment: @frabjous, revtex4-1 is also fine!

Comment: revtex4-1 doesn't define `\onecolumn` either, and both are incompatible with the `multicol` package. Maybe someone else will have an idea.

Comment: It seems that `revtex...` doesn't define either `\onecolumn` or `\twocolumn` which, to me, implies that there should be no changes within the document to the number of columns. Perhaps another class should be used or just go with a onecolumn appendix. Or could the `multicol` package be of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

Insert the following before the appendix section:

```
\clearpage
\onecolumngrid
\appendix
\pagenumbering{alph}
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
% Thesis report
%  
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,%
  nofootinbib,aps,superscriptaddress,%
  eqsecnum,prd,notitlepage,showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % generate random text, remove later...

% page number add middle bottom
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Add my name add top left corner
\lhead{author} % controls the left corner of the header
\rhead{ University }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% To get keywords in abstract
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index terms---}} #1}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{author  }
\affiliation{University}
\date{date}

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}
% Add keywords to abstract
\keywords{one, two, three}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Data}
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Results}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Conclusion\_and\_Discussion}
\begin{acknowledgments}
We thank\dots
\end{acknowledgments}
%\begin{thebibliography}{9}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliography{myrefs}
%\end{thebibliography}

\clearpage
\onecolumngrid
\appendix
\pagenumbering{alph}
\section{Appendix} % Appendix needs to be on a new full page (not two column but one column) with alphabetic page numbers.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `\onecolumngrid` is the answer here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be better to inserting the command to the MWE and show the result, so everyone can see if the question is ansered by this.